# CSS fixed div max height in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a fixed div setup using this:

```
.box {
position: fixed;
width: 600px;
bottom: 20px;
left: 50%;
max-height: 400;
overflow:auto;
}
```

The problem I have is that on internet explorer it ignores the max-height, the div just expands upwards and out of view with no scroll bars, even if I set overflow: scroll;.

BTW I am using the hack to do fixed absolute position boxes so they stay on the screen reguardless of scrolling, if that matters:

```
* { margin: 0; }
* html .box { position: absolute; }
```

Comment: Interestingly for me the expression works in ie 6+7 but no 8. In 8 neither the expression or regular css work. In 9 the expression doesn't work but the CSS does. So is IE 8 the odd one out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
* html .box{ 
height: expression( this.scrollHeight > 399 ? "400px" : "auto" ); /* fix for ie 5+ */
}
.box {
max-height: 400px; 
position: fixed;
width: 600px;
bottom: 20px;
left: 50%;
overflow:auto;
}
```